# Use character wrapper to code a replace a letter in a string with a new letter keeping the original case

Tags: java, character

Trying to figure out how to use character wrapping to mutate a string based on user input. If string is 'Bob loves to build building' and user chooses to replace all letter B/b with T/t how do I need to code it to get 'Tom loves to tuild tuildings'?

Comment: When b is being replaced with t, bob will not become Tom ;-)

Comment: Use the [`Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) wrapper. `Character.toUpperCase` and `Character.toLowerCase` will give you the two case versions of the user's input character(s).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a String class built-in replace function.

```
String text = "Bob loves to build building";
text = text.replace("B","T").replace("b","t");
```

something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple start is to know about `String.replace(char, char)` in Java.

```
// This addresses the example you gave in your question.
str.replace('B', 'T').replace('b', 't');
```

Then, you should take the user input into toReplace and replaceWith characters, figure out the uppercase/lowercase counter parts using the ASCII code and generate the arguments for the above replace method call.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws JSONException
    {
        String str = "Bob loves to build building";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        char toReplace = scanner.nextLine().trim().charAt(0);
        char replaceWith = scanner.nextLine().trim().charAt(0);

        System.out.println(str.replace(getUpper(toReplace), getUpper(replaceWith)).replace(getLower(toReplace),
            getLower(replaceWith)));
    }

    private static char getUpper(char ch)
    {
        return (char) ((ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') ? ch : ch - ('a' - 'A'));
    }

    private static char getLower(char ch)
    {
        return (char) ((ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') ? ch + ('a' - 'A') : ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to be able to convert any letter that is input by the user. How do I code it so that it will change over anything that the user puts in? It needs to come after this:                        
  System.out.print("\nWhat character would you like to     replace?");
  String letter = input.nextLine();
  System.out.print("What character would you like to replace "+letter+" with?");
  String exchange = input.nextLine();

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear (how 'b' becomes 'm' in Bob -> Tom?). However, to run case insensitive replace you should do something like this:

```
String text ="Bob loves to build building";
String b = "b";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(b, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

String outText = m.replaceAll("T");
```