# If user inputs random letter, how do I change all of that letter in a given string?

Tags: java

I am  trying to figure out how to use character wrapping to mutate a string based on user input. If string is 'Bob loves to build building' and user enters 'b' I have to make the out put change both the lower case and upper case letter bs.

This is what it must add on to:

```
 System.out.print("\nWhat character would you like to replace?");
 String letter = input.nextLine();
 System.out.print("What character would you like to replace "+letter+" with?");
 String exchange = input.nextLine();
```

Comment: Did you try anything named String.replace()?

Comment: To nitpick, you can't mutate a `String`, but you can create a new, modified `String`.

Comment: how do I do it using string then?

Comment: Isn't this duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399724/use-character-wrapper-to-code-a-replace-a-letter-in-a-string-with-a-new-letter-k ?

Comment: String mutation1;
  mutation1 = phrase.replace(letter, exchange);
  System.out.print("Mutated phrase is: "+mutation1);

Comment: That is what I originally added but then it it changed only the lower case letters when the user enters a lowercase letter or only the uppercase letters if the user enters an uppercase letter

Comment: @user1667536: Great, your halfway there. So what's the next step?

Answer (score 3):

how about:

```
myString = myString.replace(letter,exchange);
```

EDIT:
myString is the string you want to replace the letter in.

letter is taken from your code, it is the letter to be replaced.

exchange is also taken from your code, it is the string that letter is to be replace with.

Of course you would need to do this again for the upper case letter and lower case so it would be:

```
myString = myString.replace(letter.toLowerCase(),exchange);
myString = myString.replace(letter.toUpperCase(),exchange);
```

In order to cover the case where the entered letter is either lower or uppercase.

Comment: Please expand on that JTMon. I have no idea what I am supposed to do and I have been trying for 4 hours now.

Answer (score 1):

A simplistic approach would be:

```
String phrase = "I want to replace letters in this phase";
phrase = phrase.replace(letter.toLowerCase(), exchange);
phrase = phrase.replace(letter.toUpperCase(), exchange);
```

EDIT: Added toLowerCase() as per suggestion below.

Comment: @user1667536 have you though about replacing `yourString` variable with your actual String variable? You just don't copy/paste raw code from a site and try to use it without adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Would I input:  String letter = letter.replace(letter, exchange);

Comment: I would add .toLowerCase() to the first call, in case the user entered an uppercase letter.

Comment: @user1667536 No that would not work. There must be a third variable representing the string you want to replace elements in.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and you are right munyengm, that did not work.

Comment: Okay, now if user puts in 'b' exchange with 't' I am still going from "Bob" to "Bot". Something is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what you dont get about the previous replies but this ties them to your code.

```
 String foo = "This is the string that will be changed"; 
 System.out.print("\nWhat character would you like to replace?"); 
 String letter = input.nextLine(); 
 System.out.print("What character would you like to replace "+letter+" with?"); 
 String exchange = input.nextLine();
 foo = foo.replace(letter.toLowerCase(), exchange); 
 foo = foo.replace(letter.toUpperCase(), exchange); 

 System.out.print("\n" + foo); // this will output the new string
```

Comment: what does 'foo' mean or stand for?

Comment: Doing that does not take care of the problem with the upper case letter at the start of the phrase. I can get it to change every letter except the capital letter at the beginning of the sentence. For example, I can get it to turn "Bob" into "Bot" but I need it to change from "Bob" to "tot"

Comment: you are very new to programming aren't you. you have all the answers you need in the replies, you should be able to work it out from here.
also foo is just a generic name.

Comment: with still no answer accepted, i have updated my answer to show you

Answer (score 0):

Check `replace` method:

```
public String replace(char oldChar, char newChar)
```

> Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar.

For more details see [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char, char))

EDIT:

```
class ReplaceDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String inputString = "It is that, that's it.";
        Char replaceMe = 'i';
        Char replaceWith = 't';

        String newString = inputString.Replace(replaceMe.toUpperCase(), replaceWith);
        newString = newString.Replace(replaceMe.toLowerCase(), replaceWith);
    }
}
```

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: See where Azodious? Was there supposed to be something for me to click on?

Comment: I still don't know how to set that up at all. I have to add that public segment but then how do I actually code it

Comment: I need to be able to change "Bob" to "tot" and all I can do is change "Bob" to "bot" the uppercase letter is killing me.

Comment: It says invalid character content. Do I have to add anything else to get the Char to work? We have not learned Char but the instructor said we should be able to figure it out...obviously not.

Comment: within single quotes only single letter is allowed. you are doing 'letter' .. that's wrong. it should be `Char letter = 'l';`