# How do I change "Bob" to "Tot" based on random letter selection by a user?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If user inputs random letter, how do I change all of that letter in a given string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400466/if-user-inputs-random-letter-how-do-i-change-all-of-that-letter-in-a-given-stri)

A user gets to put in a favorite phrase: Bob likes building buildings.
User, what letter do you want to replace: b
User, what letter do you want to replace b with: t
Mutated phrase is: Tot likes tuilding tuidlings.

This is what I am trying to do. It must work with any letter or any phrase. Our hint is that character wrappers are easiest but that it can be done with string methods. Please someone help me. I am going on more than 4 hours on this one line and I finished the whole rest of the project with no clue how to do this last step.

Comment: How is this different from [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400466/if-user-inputs-random-letter-how-do-i-change-all-of-that-letter-in-a-given-stri)?

Comment: Same question, no answer yet. Please help me. I have no clue what to do. I can send you my java project if that helps

Comment: @user1667536: Maybe you should consider looking at the Javadoc for [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: Almost identical to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399724/use-character-wrapper-to-code-a-replace-a-letter-in-a-string-with-a-new-letter-k) which is also yours.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
String oldPhrase = "Bob likes building buildings";
String oldChar = "b";
String newChar = "t";
String newPhrase = oldPhrase.replaceAll(oldChar.toLowerCase(), newChar.toLowerCase()).replaceAll(oldChar.toUpperCase(), newChar.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: feel free to upvote/accept this answer if it fixed your problem.

Comment: One problem. If you input for example'B' to exchange with 't' it gives me "tot" instead of "Tot and if you put in b to replace with T you get "ToT" but it needs to say "Tot"

Comment: fixed? if that doesn't work you should make your requirements clearer - how should upper/lower case be handled?

Comment: Works. Thanks again. The directions were not that clear and my instructor through this in on this assignment even though it isn't discussed until the next chapter and it did not have any examples anywhere close to this to compare it to. He has had many complaints already from the assignment forum. I really appreciate your help and your patience. I have one word to define you and that is 'AWESOME'